# PasswordReminder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forgot-password

I am trying to set a Password reminder in restful way. (Following this tutorial http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#password-reminders-and-reset but trying to do it in restful way)

The route looks like this,

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
    Route::resource(
        'password', 'RemindersController',
        array(
            'only' => array('store', 'show', 'update')
        )
    ); 
});
```

RemindersController starts as,

```
public function update()
{


}
```

The password reset url is 
    http://192.x.x.x:8000/api/v1/password/3adb8b0454144ef5aeaa333faa5c575bd833e03d

From this url loading reset.blade as follows,

```
<form action="{{ action('RemindersController@update') }}" method="PUT"


...


<input type="submit" value="Reset Password"> </form>
```

But when loading this page, the form action seems to have some issues, the action url does not seem to be right.

```
<form action="http://192.x.x.x:8000/api/v1/password/%7Bpassword%7D" method="PUT">
```

What is the right way to provide action property in the form for this? How can I pass the password reset details to 'update' method in Reminder controller?

In the mentioned tutuorial it is like

```
action="{{ action('RemindersController@postReset') }}" method="POST"
```

What will change when using the restful resource way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it right by following the suggestion from this [site](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/124/opening-a-new-html-form) with the following modification,

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('api/v1/password/update') }}" method="POST">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```